# Can't get array to render to view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am currently setting up an express server that receives data from a webpage I scraped and show's the results. I cannot get this obj / array to render. I can make a completely different array render just fine.

I'm currently using path, express, hbs, axios, and cheerio. I have my hbs file that has a

{{data}}

and on my app.js I have a

```js
app.get('', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'ClearVision',
        data: newFunction(),
        name: 'Chris'
    })
})
```

Here is my code below that..

```js
const getdeals = (callback) => {
    axios(url, {
            headers: {
                Cookie: "xx=x;"
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            const html = response.data;
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);

            // Deals Page
            const statsTable = $('tbody > tr');
            const totaldeals = [];


            // Loop Table for data in each row
            statsTable.each(function () {
                const nwline = "\n"
                let date = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text()
                let bodydeals = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text()
                let newdeal = $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').text()
                let revdeal = $(this).find('td:nth-child(4)').text()
                let monthlydealrev = $(this).find('td:nth-child(5)').text()

                // Clear /n
                if (date.includes(nwline)) {
                    date = date.toString().replace("\n", ""),
                        date = date.toString().replace("\n", "")
                }

                // Clear /n
                if (bodydeals.includes(nwline)) {
                    bodydeals = bodydeals.toString().replace("\n", ""),
                        bodydeals = bodydeals.toString().replace("\n", ""),
                        bodydeals = bodydeals.toString().replace("\n", "")
                }

                // Clear /n
                if (newdeal.includes(nwline)) {
                    newdeal = newdeal.toString().replace("\n", ""),
                        newdeal = newdeal.toString().replace("\n", ""),
                        newdeal = newdeal.toString().replace("\n", "")
                }

                // Clear /n
                if (revdeal.includes(nwline)) {
                    revdeal = revdeal.toString().replace("\n", ""),
                        revdeal = revdeal.toString().replace("\n", ""),
                        revdeal = revdeal.toString().replace("\n", "")
                }

                // Clear /n (lookup jquery table functions)
                if (monthlydealrev.includes(nwline)) {
                    monthlydealrev = monthlydealrev.toString().replace("\n", ""),
                        monthlydealrev = monthlydealrev.toString().replace("\n", ""),
                        monthlydealrev = monthlydealrev.toString().replace("\n", "")
                }

                totaldeals.push({
                    date,
                    bodydeals,
                    newdeal,
                    revdeal,
                    monthlydealrev
                })



            })
            callback({
                totaldeals
            })
            //console.log(totaldeals[1].date)
        })
        .catch(console.error);

}

function newFunction() {
    //return [getdeals(result => console.log(result.totaldeals[0].newdeal))];

    return [getdeals(result => console.log(result.totaldeals))]
}
```

At the bottom right there, I can refresh the page and it will print result.totaldeals ( result is an obj and has totaldeals *an array* inside it )
If i remove the console.log and just try to return the data it won't print to console.log (obviously bc i removed it), but I can't get the data to render to screen. If I make an array like var x = [ 'one' , 'two' ] I can get that to show on the view just fine.

Comment: It seems like your `result.totaldeals` is an array of object and not array of string `[ 'one' , 'two' ]`. As well you are returning array nested in another array. Instead return the array directly or spread the inner array contents within the outer array.

Comment: @randomSoul Yes it is. I can't get it to properly render on my index.hbs file even though I have {{data}} there. If I create a random array like `var randomx = [ 'one' , 'two'  ]` and set `data: randomx;` instead of `data: newFunction()` . Then I can get that array to render. For some reason I can't get newFunction() to render on the hbs file.

Comment: @randomSoul I added a gif link to the post to show what I mean.